# How to accept any order of groups in regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

as already mentioned in my provider question, how can I change an regex with names capture groups from a dedicated order of the groups to any order is accepted?

As an example of my data:

```
{
  att1 = "demo1"
  att2 = "ohno"
}
{
  att2 = "demo1"
  att1 = "ohno"
}
```

If I use this regex, it will work for the first record but not for the second one

```
/\{[\n\s]*(?:att1 = \"(?<att1>\w*)\"[\n\s]*(?:att2 = \"(?<att2>\w*)\"[\n\s]*\}/gm
```

Connecting both groups with an | will not help. Instead it finds only the last group, but why?

```
/\{[\n\s]*(?:(?:att1 = \"(?<att1>\w*)\"[\n\s]*)|(?:(?:att2 = \"(?<att2>\w*)\"[\n\s]*)\}/gm
```

Test in online Tools do not really help because there the regex might work bot not in my local nodejs 16 version

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/(?<=\{[^}]*?)(?:att1 = "(?<att1>\w*)"|att2 = "(?<att2>\w*)")(?=[^}]*?\})/g
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<=\{[^}]*?)` - look behind for `{` and zero or more character not being `}`, as few as possible.

`(?:` - create a non capturing group with an alternation

`att1 = "` - match `att1 = "` literally

`(?<att1>\w*)` - match and capture zero or more word characters.

`"|att2 = "` - match `"` OR àtt2 = "` literally

`(?<att2>\w*)"` - match and capture zero or more word characters and `"`

`)` - end group

`(?=[^}]*?\})` - look ahead for zero or more characters not being `}` as few as possible and the final `}`

It must have the `global` flag.

Now it doesn't care about the order, but gets both.

Comment: I‘ve tried your code on regex101.com and It worked but if I use it on my local node version I only receive a value for att1 in the first match and att2 is undefined and the 2nd match has att1 undefined and att2 with a value.

Comment: Are you sure you use the `global` flag?